# We throw a die $8$ times. What is the probability of obtaining exactly two $3$s, three $1$s, three $6$s?

Tags: probability

We throw a die $8$ times.  What is the probability of obtaining exactly two $3$s, three $1$s, three $6$s?

**My work:**
The sample space  $ S:$  "The set of all solutions of throwing the die [eight times]" and $|S|:6^8$

Then the probability of getting two $3$s, three $1$s, three $6$s is $\frac{8}{6^8}$

Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: How did you get 8 in the numerator?

Comment: when we throw a dice 6^8 times and if we get exactly 2 3's then the probability is $\frac{2}{6^8}$  then for the other is similar, in consequence$\frac{2+3+3}{6^8}$    @saulspatz

Comment: That's incorrect.  Look at Remy's answer.

Comment: A good way to start on this kind of problem is to work out a smaller version by writing down all the possibilities. Suppose you throw a three sided die three times. Then there are just $27$ possibilities. What is the probability of  one $1$ and  two  $2$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the number of ways to get two 3s, three 1s and three 6s can also be seen as a simple permutation problem of $8$ digits.

Imagine the result of the $8$ throws is recorded as a sequence of $8$ numbers: $d_1 d_2 \ldots d_8$.

Now you want to know in how many different ways can occur the numbers $3,3,1,1,1,6,6,6$ in such a sequence.

Or, in other words, how many different 8-digit numbers can you create with the digits $3,3,1,1,1,6,6,6$.

- there are $8!$ permutations (arrangements) of these $8$ digits **but**
- each permutation of $3,3$ and $1,1,1$ and $6,6,6$ gives the same 8-digit number, so you get

$$\frac{8!}{2!\cdot 3! \cdot 3!} \mbox{ differnt 8-digit numbers or different throws}$$

So, the probability in question is 
$$P = \frac{8!}{2!\cdot 3! \cdot 3!}\cdot \frac{1}{6^8}$$

Answer (score 4):

There are ${8 \choose 2}$ ways to place the threes, then ${6 \choose 3}$ ways to place the ones, and then ${3 \choose 3}$ to place the remaining sixes.

All together we can arrange these groups in

$${8\choose 2}\cdot{6\choose3}=\frac{8!}{2!\cdot6!}\cdot\frac{6!}{3!\cdot3!}=\frac{8!}{2!\cdot3!\cdot3!}$$

different ways.

Notice that this is a multinomial distribution which takes the form

$$P(X_1=x_1,...,X_k=x_k)=\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_k^{x_k}$$

Let $X_3,X_1,X_6$ denote the numbers of threes, ones, and sixes observed, respectively. Then

$$P(X_3=2, X_1=3,X_6=3)=\frac{8!}{2!\cdot3!\cdot3!}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^8\approx3.334\cdot10^{-4}$$

where we do not have to take into account $X_2=X_4=X_5=0$ since $0!=1$ and $\frac{1}{6}^0=1$

**R Simulation:**

```
dice=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
u = replicate(10^7,sample(dice,8,repl=T))
one=colSums(u==1)
two=colSums(u==2)
three=colSums(u==3)
four=colSums(u==4)
five=colSums(u==5)
six=colSums(u==6)
mean(three==2 & one==3 & six==3)

[1] 0.0003365
```

which agrees with our result fairly accurately.

Comment: This is correct, so upvoted and useful to other visitors, but not likely to help the OP.

Comment: I have edited my answer which will perhaps help.